# Cross-browser blurred background?

Tags: css, cross-browser, filter, background

I want to make a menu with semi-transparent blurred background.
At the moment, I've only found a solution for IE: `filter: blur(strength=50);`.

How can I do this cross-browser, without using images?

Answer (score 1):

There is no blur property in CSS, and filters are an IE-only feature. You'll have to use images.

The only way around this is to use a second, blurred version of the image and apply that as the background. You'll need to set up a common background position to line them up, e.g. using position: fixed or calculating the offset position from the top left corner of your menu.